# Combine the values of two arrays into object

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ["Bob", "John", "Dave"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

Is there combine the two into a javascript array filled with objects that looks like:

```
[
  {meta: 'Bob', value: 1 },
  {meta: 'John', value: 2},
  {meta: 'Dave', value: 3}
]
```

Comment: There certainly is and I'd be more than happy to help you understand how. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: While I'm extremely comfortable with handling and juggling array data, I'm the complete opposite when it comes to objects, more so when combining the two. The closest I got was getting one array to be the key and the second to be the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of the ways how to achieve it. You can use `Array#forEach` function to iterate over every element from `array1`. Then, create empty object and set specified properties - in your case: `meta` and `value`. Then - assign elements to it and just push it into the `arr` variable.

```js
var array1 = ["Bob", "John", "Dave"],
    array2 = [1, 2, 3],
    arr = [];

array1.forEach(function(v,i){
  var obj = {};
  obj.meta = v;
  obj.value = array2[i];
  arr.push(obj);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much! Definitely saving this snippet.

Comment: Why would you create an empty object first rather than using an object literal to create all the properties in one statement?

Comment: @eeetee Thank you, have a great day (:

Comment: @nnnnnn Let me think, I saw that method many times on the Stack, even my JS Guru - Nina Scholz used to set objects this way. Anyways - it's just one of the ways how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break it down.

You have two arrays of equal length and you want to extract a value from each.

```
// Could also do array2.length since they're the same size
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var val1 = array1[i];
  var val2 = array2[i]
}
```

and you want to create an object using those two values

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var val1 = array1[i];
  var val2 = array2[i]
  var obj = {
    meta: val1,
    value: val2
  };
}
```

Finally, you want to store each of those generated objects in an array

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var val1 = array1[i];
  var val2 = array2[i]
  var obj = {
    meta: val1,
    value: val2
  };
  result.push(obj);
}
```

And now you have your result!

You could rewrite this in a number of ways. For example:

```
var result = array1.map(function(val1, index) {
  return {
    meta: val1,
    value: array2[index]
  };
});
```

or if you're in an environment which supports it:

```
let result = array1.map((val1, index) => (
  {
    meta: val1,
    value: array2[index]
  }
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using `Array.prototype.map()` function:

```js
var array1 = ["Bob", "John", "Dave"], 
    array2 = [1, 2, 3],
    combined = array1.map(function(v, k, a){ return {meta: v, value: array2[k]}; });
    
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object and iterate the keys and the values.

```js
var array1 = ["Bob", "John", "Dave"],
    array2 = [1, 2, 3],
    object = { meta: array1, value: array2 },
    result = Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        object[k].forEach(function (a, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][k] = a;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: overcomplicated for such simple case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, while this may be true for this case, for more properties it might work well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Chrome, you could do:

`const combined = array1.map((name,i) => ({meta: name, value: array2[i]}))`

Comment: Why Chrome important?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both support that syntax. Not sure about older versions of IE. Specifically `const` and the fat arrow syntax could be trouble.

Comment: while your solution is good, I also wanted to see Ecmascript5 version

Comment: IE11 supports `const` but not arrow functions. MS Edge supports both.

Comment: Good to know @nnnnnn