# Creating objects from arrays and collecting these objects in a one array

Tags: javascript

I want to learn this task solutions

How can I add both arrays into objects and add them to a new array?

```
nameList = ["Jhon", "Mohammad", "Peter", "Harry"];
ageList = ["21", "27", "35", "65"];

var arr = [
{
    "name" : "Jhon",
    "age" : "21"
},
{
    "name" : "Mohammad",
    "age" : "27"
},
{
    "name" : "Peter",
    "age" : "35"
},
{
    "name" : "Harry",
    "age" : "65"
}
]
```

Comment: Please note that this is not a “you teach me please” kind of site. You are supposed to at least make an attempt yourself, and present that with your question. [ask].

Comment: What have you tried so far? you should give us your effort till now.

Comment: You are right forever. It was great to hear these rules from you. I will try to pay attention to this in the next posts. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the values of two arrays into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448966/combine-the-values-of-two-arrays-into-object)

Comment: Yes. Also @NguyễnVănPhong 's answer is enough. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nameList = ["Jhon", "Mohammad", "Peter", "Harry"];
ageList = ["21", "27", "35", "65"];
var arr = [];

for(let i=0; i<nameList.length;i++){
arr.push({
   name: nameList[i],
   age: ageList[i]
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of both arrays is the same, you can use `Array#map` like this.

```js
const nameList = ["Jhon", "Mohammad", "Peter", "Harry"];
const ageList = ["21", "27", "35", "65"];

const result = nameList.map((r, index) => ({name: r, age: ageList[index]}));
console.log(result);
```

**In case that the length is different, you can try this way**

```js
const nameList = ["Jhon", "Mohammad", "Peter", "Harry"];
const ageList = ["21", "27", "35"]; // <-- missing age of Harry

let nLength = nameList.length , aLength = ageList.length, index = 0;
const result = [];
while(index < nLength && index < aLength){
  result.push({name: nameList[index], age: ageList[index]});
  index++;
}
console.log(result);
```