# Create object from two array with custom key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array:

`arrayA = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]`

`arrayB = [1, 2, 3]`

I need to make an object with these two array, but having custom keys.

Output desired:

```
{
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Banana"
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "Orange"
 }
}
```

what I have tried:

I have following some SO answer and it didnt meet my requirements:

```
result = {};
arrayA.forEach((item, i) => {
 result["id"] = arrayB[i];
 result["name"] = item;
});
```

the above code just reassign the value to the last item, hence I only got one object like this:

```
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Orange"
}
```

Comment: `arrayA.map((name, i) => ({id: arrayB[i], name}))`? I think you want an array of objects, not an object of objects, which is not a thing (you'd need keys for the object to be valid, and it's not clear what those would be)...

Comment: The result isn’t valid JavaScript. You want an array of objects, so why is your `result` an object?

Comment: I think safwansf means an array of those objects

Comment: `{{` is an invalid construct. You mean... Array `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the values of two arrays into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448966/combine-the-values-of-two-arrays-into-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use map instead

```js
const arrayA = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
const arrayB = [1, 2, 3];

const newArray = arrayA.map((item, i) => {
  return {
    "id" : arrayB[i],
    "name" : item
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: this one works, just have to change the `=` to `:`, thanks!

Comment: Of course, the ones in the duplicate question pointed out in my comment also work...