# React Array to Object conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am getting a response from json file as

```
methodTypes = ["BOTH","INSIDE","OUTSIDE"]
```

```
outputTypes = ["STANDARD","DETAILED","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_STANDARD","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_DETAILED"]
```

I want to convert it into below format using JavaScript.

```
methods = [
  {"methodKey":"BOTH","outputTypes":["STANDARD","DETAILED","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_STANDARD","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_DETAILED"]},
  {"methodKey":"INSIDE","outputTypes":["STANDARD","DETAILED","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_STANDARD","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_DETAILED"]},
  {"methodKey":"OUTSIDE","outputTypes":["STANDARD","DETAILED","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_STANDARD","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_DETAILED"]}
]
```

How can I achieve that? I tried using `array.reduce` method but, it is not working as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the values of two arrays into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448966/combine-the-values-of-two-arrays-into-object)

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const 
  methodTypes = ["BOTH","INSIDE","OUTSIDE"],
  outputTypes = ["STANDARD","DETAILED","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_STANDARD","ALL_ATTRIBUTES_DETAILED"];
  
const methods = methodTypes.map(methodKey => ({ methodKey, outputTypes: [...outputTypes] }));

console.log(methods);
```