# How to make an object with two arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have

```js
const value = [`123`, `232`, `789`, `554`, `990`]
const year = ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
```

with these two arrays, I'm trying to make an object like this.

```js
[
{value: '123', year: '2015'},
{value: '232', year: '2016'},
{value: '789', year: '2017'},
{value: '554', year: '2018'},
{value: '990', year: '2019'},
]
```

**How can I make this thing possible?**

I tried to use `map()`, however failed.

Comment: `map()` is a fine way to do it. Why did it fail?

Comment: value and year always have the same amount of elements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448966/combine-the-values-of-two-arrays-into-object got the same problem. I figured out how to do it. Thank you guys!

Comment: this is an example of how you can do it with .map https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/e0gfm54k/5/

Comment: Wow This looks easier than the link upon. Thank you Chris.